# Loading Dates From DataBase in datepicker asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to bind jquery datepicker with data from ajax call. 
The date string is coming but when it goes for `beforeShowDay`, it is not showing any thing.

My implementation til now is:

```
<div id="date"></div>
<script>
    var selectedDates = new Array();
    $(function () {
       var userId = "<%= UserID %>";
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "/WebService1.asmx/JsonGetAllDatesOfWork",
          data: '{"userId":"' + userId + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
            var availableDates = data.d;
            $.each(availableDates, function (i, item) {
            item = item.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            selectedDates.push(item);
            });
          },
            error: function (data) {
            alert('there is an error');
            }
           });
        });
       $('#date').datepicker({
             beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
             if ($.inArray(dmy, selectedDates) != -1) {
               return [true, "", "Available"];
               } else {
                  return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
                 }
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true
         });

</script>
```

Value For selectedDate is in the format

```
["20-08-2014", "21-08-2014", "22-08-2014", "27-08-2014", "28-08-2014", "29-08-2014", "09-09-2014", "18-09-2014", "19-09-2014", "21-09-2014", "23-09-2014", "25-09-2014", "13-10-2014", "14-10-2014"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your ajax call to get the data is occurring after you call beforeShowDay. The $ajax call occurs, and in the success you set values in the array, but at the same time the server is processing you call

```
$('#date').datepicker({
```

You need to ideally call the datePicker assignment in your success method. Alternatively, you need to set async: false forthe $ajax call.

Option 1:

```
<div id="date"></div>
<script>
    var selectedDates = new Array();
    $(function () {
       var userId = "<%= UserID %>";
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "/WebService1.asmx/JsonGetAllDatesOfWork",
          data: '{"userId":"' + userId + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
            var availableDates = data.d;
            $.each(availableDates, function (i, item) {
            item = item.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            selectedDates.push(item);
            });

            $('#date').datepicker({
                 beforeShowDay: function (date) {
               dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                 if ($.inArray(dmy, selectedDates) != -1) {
                   return [true, "", "Available"];
                   } else {
                      return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
                     }
                },
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                inline: true
             });
          },
            error: function (data) {
            alert('there is an error');
            }
           });
        });


</script>
```

Option 2 (not ideal since the application will hang until data comes back from the server):

```
<div id="date"></div>
<script>
    var selectedDates = new Array();
    $(function () {
       var userId = "<%= UserID %>";
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "/WebService1.asmx/JsonGetAllDatesOfWork",
          data: '{"userId":"' + userId + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
            var availableDates = data.d;
            $.each(availableDates, function (i, item) {
            item = item.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            selectedDates.push(item);
            });
          },
            error: function (data) {
            alert('there is an error');
            }
           });
        });
       $('#date').datepicker({
             beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
             if ($.inArray(dmy, selectedDates) != -1) {
               return [true, "", "Available"];
               } else {
                  return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
                 }
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true
         });

</script>
```

Comment: nops i found out the problem this one was really tricky, basically datepicker is looking for the format in this way [d-m-yy] for eg if 9-10-2014 and the returned string contains the date format[dd-mm-yy]. so there is no 09-10-2014 in the date chamber that's why its not mapping the datepicker. 
Only i needed was to provide the date format like d-mm-yy

Comment: Well that's annoying. You should definitely answer your own question, since I have to think others will have the problem.